# I need to put up a border for my video in html

Tags: html, css

```css
.movie.mp4{
 border:5px solid red;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>movie</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<div id="logo">
<h1>
Mysite
</h1>
<span>
movie
</span>
</div>
 <video class="stream" src="videos/movie.mp4" controls width="1000px" height="400px">
    <object data="videos/movie.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="videos/movie.mp4"/>
    </object>
</video> 
 </video> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

This is my code I run in chrome using `notepad++.`
I need to put up a white border for the video. Please help!!

Comment: where is the class 'movie' ? and class 'mp4' ? The question has been answered but do you understand how it works ? the '.' is selecting a class. As you have nothing with class 'movie' it wont do anything. But you do have class 'stream' so use that instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add css as

```
.stream{
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thanks........! it worked!!!

Comment: @Arun.kumar.M ,sorry for the delay i figured out recently how to accept an answer.. am kinda new here..!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the video in a div and give it a border.

```css
.border{
 border:5px solid red;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>movie</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
<div id="logo">
<h1>
Mysite
</h1>
<span>
movie
</span>
</div>
<div class="border">
 <video class="stream" src="videos/movie.mp4" controls width="1000px" height="400px">
    <object data="videos/movie.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="videos/movie.mp4"/>
    </object>
</video> 
 </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```